# Strange Microsoft.Owin DLL issue and Nuget

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I cleaned up some DLL references in an ASP.NET MVC project, I deleted the DLLs in the bin and updated source control to remove the DLLs from source control. I copy all the references to bin on build now, the right way. But when I run localhost I get the error:

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationDescription' from assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

So I started comparing DLLs on the server (where the website is working), to my local bin directory. If I copy and replace Microsoft.Own from the server and overwrite my local version, the website works again, error gone.

**The thing is the versions of the DLLs are exactly the same, see the following screen shot:**

[image]

On the left is my local copy, and on the right is the version from the server.

If I look at my References for the ASP.NET MVC Website, I see that Microsoft.Own is located at:
..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.2.1.0\lib**net40**\Microsoft.Owin.dll

And Copy Local is set to True, see screen shot:
[image]

So next I deleted the reference for Microsoft.Owin.2.1.0 and tried to readd using the net45 version of Microsoft.Owin.dll instead. So I browsed to ..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.2.1.0\lib**net45**\Microsoft.Owin.dll

But when I went to check the Properties for Microsoft.Owin, under References, the path was still
..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.2.1.0\lib**net40**\Microsoft.Owin.dll

So I then went to my csproj file and saw the following entry:

```
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.2.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

And in my web.config my targetFramework is 4.5:

```
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
```

So finally, I copied and pasted the Microsoft.Owin.dll on the server, that works to 
..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.2.1.0\lib**net40**\Microsoft.Owin.dll and ..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.2.1.0\lib**net45**\Microsoft.Owin.dll

To overwrite the package DLL being copied when I Rebuild and STILL I get the error:

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationDescription' from assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

Again, if I copy the Microsoft.Owin.dll that is the same version as my local copy, and overwrite my local copy of Microsoft.Owin.dll in the bin, my ASP.NET MVC starts working again, until I build again that is of course.

Comment: Try running `Update-Package –reinstall <packageName>` for each of the Katana/OWIN related packages (http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/reinstalling-packages). You should not need to add references directly to any DLLs if what you're using is NuGet packages.

Comment: That didn't work, thanks though

Answer (score 1):

First check both dll size is same?If size is different then dll are different.

Follow following steps.

- Open the project
- Remove dll.
- Build project now. You will get error.
- Close project
- Open project again
- Don't build project
- Clean solution
- Add dll and reference
- Build project
- You will get success

Comment: Thanks for you help, the DLLs are not the same size, my localhost project is using net40 package and my server has the net45 but no matter how many types I delete the reference, build, close the project, clean the solution, try and Microsoft.Owin net45 the reference always goes to net40

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that some assembly file in "bin" directory which is depended on the error loading assembly.So you should check the project references and clean "bin" directory.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else who comes here (or future me), Owin dll changed from version 1.0.0 to 1.0 ..so you can follow the steps listed by Manjurhusen or just look if your reference needs to be renamed from 1.0.0 to 1.0